# Measure time in minutes in C

Tags: c, macos, time

I am writing a program that will need to measure time in minutes.

To be exact, it will wait 10 minutes, execute some code, wait 2 minutes, execute more code and repeat this 5 times (anyone guess what I'm trying to do?) and I am wondering how to do the breaks.

Thanks in advance!

Oh, and by the way, I'm on Mac.

Comment: http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sleep.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
sleep(600); // sleep ten minutes
sleep(120); //sleep two minutes
```

OR if that doesn't work, it'll be usleep, which takes miliseconds as argument I believe. (1 second = 1000)

Comment: Note though that `sleep()` can wake up early if your process recieves a signal, so you will need to check how much time has actually elapsed (using eg. `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...)` before and after the sleep) and possibly sleep again.

Answer (score 2):

[`sleep(3)`](http://www.manpages.info/macosx/sleep.3.html)